# How to using AWS S3 Java v2 SDK to talk to S3 compatible storage (minio)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, minio

I am trying to use software.amazon.awssdk:s3 S3Client to talk to a minio storage, but I cant find this in the official document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/using.html

Looks like it only supports AWS S3 service, the region config is compulsory.

I searched the internet but they are using v1 SDK.

Here is my S3Client but when I use an api it throws `oftware.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Received an UnknownHostException when attempting to interact with a service.` The hostname was modified as `backend.localhost` in the request.

```
String endpoint = "http://localhost:9000"
return S3Client
        .builder()
        .region(Region.of("minio"))
        .endpointOverride(new URI(endpoint))
        .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey))
        .build();

// the request
s3Client.listObjects(ListObjectsRequest.builder().bucket("backend").build())
```

Comment: You can override the S3 endpoint with `S3Client.builder().endpointOverride(yourUrl)`. I'm not sure that not providing a region will throw any exception, as you can instanciate any Region you like through `Region.of()`

Comment: @Raphallal It is required so I've use the region Region.AWS_GLOBAL. Now I updated my S3Client builder config with `minio` region, but it seems that the SDK is trying to connect AWS.

Comment: I've seen on the [minio github](https://github.com/minio/minio/discussions/15063) that you should use the `us-east-1`region.

Comment: I tried with `us-east-1` but still the same issue with `Region.AWS_GLOBAL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across the same problem. My provisional solution was to create a custom endpoint provider. I've only tested this on getObject with minio so I don't know if it will work on other methods, but theoretically it should.

```
s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                    .endpointProvider(new S3EndpointProvider() {
                        @Override
                        public CompletableFuture<Endpoint> resolveEndpoint(S3EndpointParams endpointParams) {
                            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Endpoint.builder()
                                    .url(URI.create(awsS3EndpointUrl + "/" + endpointParams.bucket()))
                                    .build());
                        }
                    })
                    // SDK requires us to provide region for local development, so we use a placeholder region here.
                    // The local instance doesn't have a specified region.
                    .region(Region.AWS_GLOBAL)
                    .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create(awsAccessKeyId, awsAccessKeySecret))
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK **can** be used with other S3-compatible storage, but the parameter names and values to use are all-but-impossible to discern from the AWS docs.  This works fine:

```
 constructor (endPoint = 'play.min.io', accessKey = 'Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F', secretKey = 'zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG', region = 'us-east-1') {
    const sslEnabled = !/\blocalhost\b|\b127.0.0.1\b|\b10.0.0.2\b/.test(endPoint);
    if (!endPoint.startsWith('http')) {
      endPoint = (sslEnabled ? 'https://' : 'http://') + endPoint;
    }
    if (!/:\d{1,5}\/?$/.test(endPoint)) {
      endPoint += ':9000';
    }

    this.#S3Client = new S3Client({
      forcePathStyle: true,
      region,
      endpoint: endPoint,
      sslEnabled,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: accessKey,
        secretAccessKey: secretKey,
        Version: 1
      }
    });
  }
```

Don't worry, that access key is the public shared access key for play.min.io